# MemoryCache and multiple per call WCF services

Tags: c#, wcf, caching, iis, memorycache

Is using the `MemoryCache` class a valid option if I want the cached data to be visible across multiple WCF services (with **PerCall** instance mode)?

There are two cases:

1. the services are all hosted in the same app in IIS
2. the services are hosted in different IIS applications on the same server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*`1.the services are all hosted in the same app in IIS`*

the answer is yes   if you are using `MemoryCache.Default` as your default cache object
From **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.default.aspx)**

*`This property always returns a reference to the default cache instance. For typical application scenarios, only one instance of MemoryCache is required.`*

you could  use it like the following

```
ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
```

Is it possible to configure it in  the following way

```
<system.runtime.caching>
 <memoryCache>
  <namedCaches>
   <add name="Default" physicalMemoryLimitPercentage="20"/>
  </namedCaches>
 </memoryCache>
</system.runtime.caching>
```

from your others services instance you can access your memory cache like the following

```
List<string> cacheKeys = MemoryCache.Default.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList();

foreach (string cacheKey in cacheKeys)
          MemoryCache.Default.Remove(cacheKey);
```

*`2.the services are hosted in different IIS applications on the same server`*

this will  be a bit tricky but it will remains a valid option you can create a dedicated webservice for caching that can be used by others webservices using the `netnamedPipeBinding` given that are on the same server

Comment: "Is it possible to configure it in the following way "

Where is this configuration occurring?  IS this in the web.config??

Comment: yes it's still possible to configure it in this way in web.config